# ip4 address of server from asp.net HttpContext C#

Tags: asp.net

I need the IP address of the server that is serving up my ASP.NET page. Can I get that from my own code on an ASP.NET page? I had hoped it might be in the HttpContext, but that's probably a naive assumption.

```
// This is NOT what I want
// This is the URL I see in the browser
// I want the IP address of the server instead
string IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. But it does not use `HttpContext`.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;

var ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).FirstOrDefault();
string ip4 = ip.ToString();
```